service worker doesn't work as expected doesn't return cached response instead fails
Hello I want to implement behavior when new deployed version to production doesn't make application crash for users that use that page.
E.g. User uses site , we deploy new version and after some time if user requests some js chunk or anything else that might change will get 404 error and will result to fail
So what I want to achieve is that user will get fallback on that missing file if network request resulted as fail
as far as I understand it is Network First strategy as per articles from google workbox-webpack-plugin
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
      exclude: [/\.*/],
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /\.js$/,
          handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        },
      ],
    })

So basically I want all my js files cached in case of fail.
But when I wanted to reproduce this issue, I removed main.js file from s4 and refreshed page in my browser and expected my page to not fail, but it shows 200 from SW but doesn't get any result from it. Why?
